# mongo db query for array inside array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with such documents, and i need to find out all documents which has `dispatchDateTime` less than `dispatchDetails.deliveryInformation.eventDate`

````
{
  "trackingCode":"T1",
  dispatchDetails: [
    {
      dispatchDateTime: "2020-12-31T22:30:02.000Z",
      deliveryInformation: [
        {
          eventDate: "2020-05-15T23:46:00.000Z",
          eventCode: "E1"
        },
        {
          eventDate: "2020-05-15T23:46:00.000Z",
          eventCode: "E2"
        },
        {
          eventDate: "2020-05-15T23:46:00.000Z",
          eventCode: "E3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "trackingCode":"T2",
  dispatchDetails: [
    {
      dispatchDateTime: "2020-12-31T22:30:02.000Z",
      deliveryInformation: [
        {
          eventDate: "2020-12-31T23:46:00.000Z",
          eventCode: "E1"
        },
        {
          eventDate: "2020-12-31T23:46:00.000Z",
          eventCode: "E2"
        },
        {
          eventDate: "2020-12-31T23:46:00.000Z",
          eventCode: "E3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "trackingCode":"T3",
  dispatchDetails: [
    {
      dispatchDateTime: "2020-12-31T22:30:02.000Z",
      deliveryInformation: [
        {
          eventDate: "2020-05-12T23:46:00.000Z",
          eventCode: "E1"
        },
        {
          eventDate: "2020-05-12T23:46:00.000Z",
          eventCode: "E2"
        },
        {
          eventDate: "2020-05-12T23:46:00.000Z",
          eventCode: "E3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}```

Any ideas?
In the above sample documents that query will return two documents with trackingCode T1 and T3
````

Answer (score 0):

Try with following query:-

```
db.collection.find({"dispatchDetails":{$elemMatch:{"dispatchDateTime":{$lt:"deliveryInformation.$.eventDate"}}}}})
```